# Kendo Grid Keep Filter State After I Go To Another Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a problem when trying to keep selected filtered elements . I have the following scenario i filter by something then i click on a row and it takes me to a new page for editting, when i go back the filter dissapears (it should not) . Please help me with this

mention: i am not using mvc grid just a simple javascript one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)(or even [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) if you want the filters to expire when browser/tab is closed) for that. DataSource has an event called [`change`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#events-change) which is called everytime a change is performed, including filtering. Inside this event you can get the Kendo's filter object (with specific structure) and save it to the storage. On the grid initialization parameters, you may set the dataSource's [`filter`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-filter) property, which expects the the filter object mentioned above and the grid will be automatically filtered in its initialization. Check the following code:

1. Get filters before grid's initialization:

   ```
   var filters = localStorage.getItem("gridFilters");

   if (filters)
   {
       filters = JSON.parse(filters);
   }
   ```
2. Then set these properties to your dataSource:

   ```
   change: function(e) 
   {
       // This saves the filter object to the storage
       localStorage.setItem("gridFilters", JSON.stringify(e.sender._filter));
   },
   filter: filters
   ```

<kbd>**[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/IwaWo)**</kbd>

Note that you didn't provided your grid specifications, so I'm guessing you're ano filtering in server side. If you do, the above code would not work and you have to try another approach. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for this suggestion, the only problem is that i keep getting this error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u at this line most likely : var filters = localStorage.getItem("gridFilters");

Comment: Can you show me what returns from `localStorage.getItem("gridFilters")`, the pure string itself ?

Comment: i keep getting filters as undefined in google chrome debugger

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/6joo7njDXQE.. You can find attached a picture

Comment: Its better to add to your post the initialization code for the grid, most useful I think.

Comment: i have a 570 lines of code grid ..

Comment: At least the dataSource and column fields ?